# flink-rpc-akka-loader - Security Vulnerability Issues

Tags: java, apache-flink

I get **Security Issues** (CVE-2019-20444, CVE-2019-20445) with threat level 9 for all the versions of the jars flink-rpc-akka-loader, flink-rpc-akka while scanning. Anyone faced this issue? Please share your resolution. Thanks.
[flink-rpc-akka-loader_vulnerable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPzQJ.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.